# Trouble with calling a stored procedure within an stored procedure and setting result as a variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from another stored procedure and store the value in a variable. The inner stored procedure basically checks if something exists and uses a select statement to return a zero or one. I keep getting an error. In this situation, MySQL is saying "=" is not valid at this position, expecting ";"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CardNames_Add` (searchedCard VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN    
    DECLARE exist TINYINT;
    EXECUTE exist = CardNames_CheckExist searchedCard
    IF (exist = 0)
        INSERT INTO card_names (name)
        VALUE(searchedCard)
END
```

Comment: EXECUTE exist = CardNames_CheckExist searchedCard;  doesn't work in mysql can you explain what that should do?

Comment: Yeah! I have a stored procedure called CardNames_CheckExist and it takes an input of VARCHAR which would be the searchedCard value. The CardNames_CheckExist stored procedure retruns either SELECT TRUE or SELECT FALSE. So I want the output to be stored in the variable exist

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite you other stored procedure, that you don't need btw, to give back a result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CardNames_CheckExist (IN searchedCard VARCHAR(50), OUT result TINYINT )
BEGIN
  --do some stuzff
  result = 1
END


CREATE PROCEDURE `CardNames_Add` (searchedCard VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN    

    CALL CardNames_CheckExist(searchedCard,@result);
    IF (@result = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO card_names (name)
        VALUES (searchedCard);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out! Thank you!